# Utilizing rails helper and controller methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Suppose I have a Rails app that deals with Posts and Comment objects. A Post `has_many` Comments and each Comment `belongs_to` a Post.

Each Comment has a `word_count` property. The Post object has an `average_comment_word_count` property which is an average of each of the Comment's `word_count`.

First question is if the Post object gets modified asynchronously (comments get added which affects the average word count), at what point should I recalculate the property? When the object is returned? Or each time a new comment is added? Does it go into the comment or post helper methods? Which controller function should call this method?

Also when I include the following Post helper method, I get a NULL value returned as JSON.

```
def average_word_count
  @average_word_count = 0
  # current_user returns the current user object
  # user has_many posts and each post belongs_to a user
  current_user.posts.find(params[:id]).comments.each do |comment|
        @average_word_count += comment.word_count / current_user.posts.find(params[:id]).comments.count
  end

  @average_word_count
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post

  after_save :update_post_word_count

  def update_post_word_count
    average_wc = post.comments.average(:word_count)
    post.update_attributes average_comment_word_count: average_wc
  end      
end
```

Or, derive it only when you need it:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  def average_comment_word_count
    comments.average :word_count
  end
end
```

Or, if it's just used once somewhere with low traffic, brazenly flout the Law of Demeter and just calculate it as needed from a post object:

```
Average Comment Word Count: <%= @post.comments.average :word_count %>
```

Update: As @coreward notes, the first part of this answer isn't useful for asynchronous updates, but the rest of the answer may still be helpful.

Comment: This does a lot of additional querying *and* it fails to account for asynchronous queries.

Comment: @coreyward, good point on the asynch queries, but I don't see the additional querying. Each post.comments.average(:foo) creates a single sql statement.

Comment: I find this approach easier to implement (and more general) than the customer counter cache, so that's why I am marking it as accepted.

Comment: @mori For every post you're triggering that additional query. If a list of posts is returned, you're performing a litany of queries to recalculate data.

Answer (score 1):

You would be a lot better off just building a custom counter cache based on what's already in ActiveModel that keeps track of the *total number of words*, then just count comments to do math manually.

```
# you need a comments_count column and a words_count column in this table
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  def avg_words_per_comment
    words_count / comments_count
  end
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
  after_save { update_counters(post.id, :words => word_count }
  before_destroy { update_counters(post.id, :words => -word_count }
end

# And in your view:

<p> 
  The average comment for this post has <%= @post.avg_words_per_comment %> words.
</p>
```

Then you don't need to worry about asynchonicity and the calculation on view is minimal.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb#L65

Comment: I'm not using Rails view templates, instead I am sending out a JSON response. Does that change anything about your answer, besides the views part?

Comment: Also I am trying to wrap my head around performing mathematical operations on numerical object properties. Counting words is a great solution IMO but not a general case one. Thanks for the answer though :)

Comment: @AndrewBarinov I literally did all the work, just output the parameter in your JSON instead of HTML (JSON is a view, btw). I don't know what you are going on about "mathematical operations on numerical object properties" though. You already have a `word_count` method on Comment according to your post, and `post#words_count` and `post#comments_count` are both just accessors for numeric columns in the database.